# How to call a Graphics2D method in other method, in java?

Tags: java, swing, methods, graphics, paint

How can I call the paint method in game method?

If i call with command the "new paint();" it doesn't work

```
// Main
public Game() {
    super();
    setTitle("Breakout");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500, 500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

// Grafica
class paint extends JPanel {

    public paint(Graphics2D g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);

    }

}
```

Comment: You can't do that.  Instead, you need to redraw the entire game every time it paints.

Answer (score 0):

Most programmers use the protected swing method paintComponent(Graphics g) in the JPanel super class to anonymously call repaint() to alter game values and change the visual appearance of the component. Using a SwingTimer will update the results over a predetermined amount of time.

```
public class game extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

      int camX, camY;
      int update_time = 5;// in milliseconds...
      Graphics2D g2d;
      Image image;
      Timer t;

     public game(){

          t = new Timer(update_time, this);// given "this" is an ActionListener...
          t.start();// calls actionPerformed method every 5ms...

     }


     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            repaint();//calls paintComponent() method...

     }


      public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

          super.paintComponent(g);
          g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

          g2d.drawImage(image, camX, camY, this);
          //Do graphical stuff
      }



}
```